# ValidationMixin missing required function, race condition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

Every time I hit my login page, it won't render due to the error

> validationMixin__.a.required is not a function

I have tried simplifying the import by changing it to the direct path

> from '@leadlucky/leadlucky-themes/src/mixins/validationMixin.js'

but all it changes in the error is

> leadlucky_themes__.b.required is not a function.

to

> validationMixin__.a.required is not a function

So I tracked it down to the "required" function inside validationMixin.js. This file comes from another project of mine that is npm linked. (npm link @leadlucky/leadlucky-themes)

Here is the validationMixin.js (with the "required" method that IS there) along with the section of code causing issues along:

[Imgur to pics](https://imgur.com/a/npT5iHw)

Here is the console error:
[image: Imgur link]

The page is expected to render my login page. My best guess is that it's some race condition where validationMixin.js is not getting imported before it's executed. How do I fix this? It works fine on all other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Woo solved it after 5 hours and a lot of research. So turns out it was a sort of race condition, data() was calling the JS file before anything was declared. Fixed that by replacing everything with a const called mixin outside of export default.

Secondly, if it's telling you VariableName.method('blah') is not a function in your data, try adding a [0] at the end.

```
 data: function() {

      return {
        username: {value: "", validator: validationMixin.required('Username')[0]},
        password: {value: "", validator: validationMixin.passwordRules[0]},
        passwordConfirm: {value: "", validator: 'x'}
}}
```

Here is my updated mixin code:

```
function buildRules(regExps = [], fns = [], errorMessages = ["Input is invalid"]){
  return [(field) => {
    if(!field) {
      return errorMessages[0];
    }

    let errMessage = null;
    let i = 1;
    regExps.every((exp) => {
      if(!exp.test(field)){
        errMessage = i < errorMessages.length ? errorMessages[i] : errorMessages[0];
        return false;
      }
      i++;
      return true;
    });
    if (!errMessage) {
      fns.every((fn) => {
        if (!fn(field)) {
          errMessage = i < errorMessages.length ? errorMessages[i] : errorMessages[0];
          return false;
        }
        i++;
        return true;
      });
    }

    return errMessage || true;
  }]
}

const mixin = {}
  mixin.emailRules = buildRules(
    [/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/],
    [],
    ['Invalid email']
  );

  mixin.userIdRules = buildRules(
  [/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/],
  [],
  ['Invalid username']
  );

  mixin.passwordRules = buildRules(
  [],
  [
    pwd => pwd.length >= 8,
    pwd => /.*[A-Z].*/.test(pwd) && /.*[a-z].*/,
    pwd => /.*[0-9].*/.test(pwd),
    pwd => /.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+[{}\]| /\\.,<>`~'";:?].*/.test(pwd)
  ],
  [
    'You must create a password',
    'Password must be at least 8 characters',
    'Password must contain upper and lowercase letters',
    'Password must contain a number',
    'Password must contain a special character',
  ]
);

mixin.required = (fieldName) => buildRules([],[],[`${fieldName} is required`]);

mixin.checkedRule = (message) => buildRules([],[],[message]);

mixin.passwordsMatch = (originalPassword) => buildRules(
  [],[(validatePassword) => validatePassword === originalPassword],
  ['Passwords must match']
);

mixin.urlRule = buildRules(
  [],
  [(url) => {
    if(url.toLowerCase().startsWith('http://')){
      url = url.substring('http://'.length)
    }
    if(url.toLowerCase().startsWith('https://')){
      url = url.substring('https://'.length)
    }
    return /[A-z|0-9]+\.[A-z|0-9]{2,22}/.test(url)
  }],
  ['Invalid URL']
);

mixin.pageIdRule = buildRules([/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/], [], 'Invalid Page Id')

export default mixin
```

Lastly, I had to add the JS file as a mixin rather than a component or trying to directly use it.